# how to strcat or strcopy a c string from given index?

Tags: c, c-strings

For example having string:

```
Hello World!
```

How to make strcopy function working from position 6 and copy only `World!` to another buffer ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char source[] = "Hello World!";
char destination[7]; // 7 = strlen("World!") + 1

strcpy(destination, source + 6);
```